# Basic operation geometrical meaning

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, matrices

What is the geometrical meaning of doing 
$x^TAx \;$?

$Ax \; $ is trivially "applying A to x", but then, what the multiplication for $x^T$ stands for?

Comment: Mattia, this question would be better received in our sister site [Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) than here. Mathoverflow is devoted to mathematical research questions.

Answer (score 1):

In $x^TAx$, you should not think of $A$ as a linear operator; you should think of $A$ as defining a bilinear form or quadratic.  If you take $A=I$, the identity matrix, then $x^Tx$ is the dot product of the vector $x$ with itself and $x^Ty$ is the dot product of the vectors $x$ and $y$; taking a different $A$ is replacing the dot product by a new bilinear form in which the product of the $i$th and $j$th standard basis vectors is $a_{ij}$.